# No result in Kibana visualization for aggregation of terms

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I'm using Kibana 6 to display aggregations from terms indexed in ElasticSearch 6.

I'm encoutering an issue while displaying a bucket aggregating terms (bidRequest.site.domain.keyword) by keywords whereas the records are effectively present in the Index and date range is okay:

[image: No results]

I don't understand why there is no result despite having those in the Index:
[image: Results]

Here's my mapping:

```
{
"mapping": {
    "BidRequestRecord": {
    "properties": {
        "bidRequest": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "allimps": {
            "type": "integer"
            },
            "app": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "bundle": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "cat": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "domain": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ext": {
                "type": "object"
                },
                "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "keywords": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "pagecat": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "publisher": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "ext": {
                    "type": "object"
                    },
                    "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                },
                "storeurl": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ver": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            },
            "at": {
            "type": "integer"
            },
            "badv": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
            },
            "bcat": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
            },
            "cur": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
            },
            "device": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "carrier": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "connectiontype": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "devicetype": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "didmd5": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "didsha1": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "dnt": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "dpidmd5": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "dpidsha1": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ext": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "is_app": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
                },
                "geo": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "country": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "lat": {
                    "type": "float"
                    },
                    "lon": {
                    "type": "float"
                    },
                    "region": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "type": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "zip": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                },
                "ifa": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ip": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "js": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "language": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "make": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "model": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "os": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "osv": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ua": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            },
            "ext": {
            "type": "object"
            },
            "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
            },
            "imp": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "banner": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "api": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "battr": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "btype": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "expdir": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "ext": {
                    "type": "object"
                    },
                    "format": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "ext": {
                        "type": "object"
                        },
                        "h": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "w": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "h": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "hmax": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "hmin": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "mimes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "pos": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "topframe": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "w": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "wmax": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "wmin": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
                },
                "bidFloorFloat": {
                "type": "float"
                },
                "bidfloor": {
                "type": "double"
                },
                "bidfloorInEur": {
                "type": "double"
                },
                "bidfloorcur": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "displaymanager": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "displaymanagerver": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ext": {
                "type": "object"
                },
                "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "iframebuster": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "instl": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "native": {
                "type": "object"
                },
                "pmp": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "deals": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "at": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "bidFloorFloat": {
                        "type": "float"
                        },
                        "bidFloorInEuro": {
                        "type": "double"
                        },
                        "bidFloorInEuroFloat": {
                        "type": "float"
                        },
                        "bidfloor": {
                        "type": "double"
                        },
                        "bidfloorcur": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "ext": {
                        "type": "object"
                        },
                        "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "wadomain": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "wseat": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "ext": {
                    "type": "object"
                    },
                    "private_auction": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
                },
                "secure": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "tagid": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "video": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "api": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "battr": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "boxingallowed": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "companionad": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "api": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "battr": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "btype": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "expdir": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "ext": {
                        "type": "object"
                        },
                        "format": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "ext": {
                            "type": "object"
                            },
                            "h": {
                            "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "w": {
                            "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "h": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "hmax": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "hmin": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "mimes": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        "pos": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "topframe": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "w": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "wmax": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "wmin": {
                        "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "companiontype": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "ext": {
                    "type": "object"
                    },
                    "h": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "linearity": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "maxbitrate": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "maxduration": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "mimes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "minbitrate": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "minduration": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "playbackmethod": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "pos": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "protocols": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "startdelay": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "w": {
                    "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            },
            "regs": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "coppa": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "ext": {
                "type": "object"
                }
            }
            },
            "site": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "cat": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "domain": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "ext": {
                "type": "object"
                },
                "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "keywords": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "page": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "pagecat": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }                    
                }
            }
            },
            "source": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "ext": {
                "type": "object"
                },
                "fd": {
                "type": "integer"
                },
                "pchain": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "tid": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        },
        "bidRequestDate": {
        "type": "date"
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to use only Bidrequest.site.domain in your field without the .keyword ?

Comment: Well, I can't because it's a combolist with already defined terms.

Comment: check also the management of you indexes if you can find a field named bidrequest.site.domain.keyword, if it's ok show it on your discovery it could be empty.

Comment: what are you counting in your metrics? you did a split to have different visualization but your metrics could be empty. Can you show what are counting ?

Comment: Well, I found something else strange. If I filter on the term in Discover section, I get no records. Like if term is not searchable

Comment: I've figured it out. I was using an old index with wrong mappings.

Comment: oh happy for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apologies for this one, I was using a not up-to-date index and at that time mapping was wrong. Works perfect with the correctly set mapping.